# My Mac wont recognise .CSS file types

Tags: css

My mac computer running OS X yosmite doesn't seem to recognise any file type with the `.css` extension. It shows as `.exe` and no matter the editor I use to save the files as a `.css`, it just won't recognise it.

I can't develop a jQuery mobile application because of this problem. Including the script file in any html document won't work.

Here is a screenshot of the problem: [image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of this directory with the info list view.

Comment: That looks like a folder full of css files. Do you mean you can't open them?

Comment: This question is a bit of topic for SO. If you open the terminal for this directory, and write `ls -la` in it what rights are shown for those `.css` files? It should be something like `-rw-r--r--`. `[...] Including the script file in any html document won't work.[...]` that's most likely a different problem, because a locally running webserver should still set the correct mime type.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the .css file
2. Choose "Get info"
3. Open the select list "Open with"
4. Choose an other app than the terminal. Something like "CSSEdit", "sublime text", "atom", "VS studio", "xcode", etc... whichever you are comfortable with
5. Eventually, you can click on "Change All" button to set this setting for all the .css files